# Reuse or $ref requestTemplates in yaml

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway

It is possible to reuse schema definitions with `$ref`. Is there a similar method for reusing **string values**, like the `requestTemplates` for Amazon's API Gateway extensions?

I've tried these methods, but both produce errors (I am not very familiar with YAML)

```
requestTemplates:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MappingTemplate"

definitions:
  MappingTemplate:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      application/json: "the template"
```

and

```
requestTemplates:
          application/json: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/MappingTemplate"

definitions:
  MappingTemplate: "the template"
```

How can I use a `$ref` for `requestTemplates`?

Answer (score 0):

References are currently supported for model schemas only. However, this should be possible with a local modification to upgrade the Swagger parser version in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about this modification

Answer (score -2):

Yes, references are supported in many parts of the swagger definition.  If you look at the [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md), you will see that references are allowed for path items, parameters, model definitions, etc.  And each of those can be relative (in the same file) or absolute (into different http locations).

Comment: I think you are confused. The `requestTemplates` section is not a path item. parameter, or model definition. If this is possible though, please explain *how* it is possibe, as my question demonstrates the standard method used by models does not work. Simply telling me that it *is* possible is not very useful.

Comment: I'm pointing you to the specific sections of the specification where references are allowed.  As mentioned in my response, you can add references--remote or local--to any of the path items, parameters, model definitions or model properties.

Comment: So are you saying that references are not allowed for string values? That seems to be what the specific section of the specification you pointed to is saying, but your answer starts out with "yes". I am confused.

Comment: The answer `yes` was to your specific question `It is possible to reuse schema definitions with $ref`?  The answer is still `yes`.  However, you cannot arbitrarily add `$ref` pointers wherever you like.  You must follow what the specification allows for pointer locations.  If you want to provide more information on your use case, I can give a proper answer, but your example isn't even valid YAML.

Comment: That isn't a question, it's a statement. "It is possible..." is a statement. I didn't even put a `?` the end, *you added that*. The next sentence, "**is there a similar method**" is the question I asked. So the answer to my question was "no"

Comment: OK, I'm just here trying to help, nothing in this for me.  Good luck